# how to join multiple table fetch data in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $mls=$_POST['mls_number'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM listing_master_residential
     , listing_master_condo 
    , listing_master_commercial  
    INNER JOIN listing_master_residential AS res ON res.Ml_num=Ml_num
    INNER JOIN listing_master_condo AS con ON con.Ml_num=Ml_num
    INNER JOIN listing_master_commercial AS com ON com.Ml_num=Ml_num
     WHERE Ml_num='$mls'";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    foreach( $result as $row){
        echo $row->Lot_code."<br/>";
        echo $row->Ml_num."<br/>";
        echo $row->Acres;
        echo $row->Addr."<br/>";
        echo $row->Bath_tot;
        echo $row->Br;
        echo $row->Br_plus;
    }

}

 }
```

please check my code  they show an error code

Column 'Ml_num' in where clause is ambiguous

thank you in advance
please help me .. where i am wrong 
?

Comment: It seems you try to cross join then inner join. remove ", listing_master_condo 
    , listing_master_commercial " And it should work. Also note that you have column with same name on all the tables "Ml_num" You should tell Mysql which table you use this column from every where in the query.

Comment: hi please help me where and how i call

Comment: It looks like there are multiple columns named `Ml_num` in these tables, and you need add a alias for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM listing_master_residential AS res
       INNER JOIN listing_master_condo AS con ON con.Ml_num=res.Ml_num
       INNER JOIN listing_master_commercial AS com ON com.Ml_num=con.Ml_num    
       WHERE res.Ml_num='$mls'";
```

Comment: hi this is not working please help me i want to fetch data from database i have three table in my database like listing_master_residential and listing_master_condo and listing_master_commercial there are three table and here is one primary key Ml_num in all table here i want to search data form one table these match mls number which table. thank you sir

Comment: please give me some suggestions

Comment: have you any idea how to fetch data from from single table which match condition.?

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM listing_master_residential
     **, listing_master_condo 
    , listing_master_commercial**
    INNER JOIN listing_master_residential AS res ON res.Ml_num **=Ml_num**
    INNER JOIN listing_master_condo AS con ON con.Ml_num **=Ml_num**
    INNER JOIN listing_master_commercial AS com ON com.Ml_num **=Ml_num**
     WHERE **Ml_num='$mls'";**

There are several mistakes here:

1. You try to use multiple type of joins with same tables:
   ("," between table names means that you try CROSS JOIN)
2. column Ml_num is ambigous as MySQL tells you (you should use table_name.Ml_num on each place you use it.

   `$sql = "SELECT * FROM listing_master_residential AS lmr
           INNER JOIN listing_master_residential AS res ON res.Ml_num=lmr.Ml_num
           INNER JOIN listing_master_condo AS con ON con.Ml_num=lmr.Ml_num
           INNER JOIN listing_master_commercial AS com ON com.Ml_num=lmr.Ml_num
            WHERE lmr.Ml_num='$mls'";`

I think this should work.

Comment: hi this is not working please help me i want to fetch data from database i have three table in my database like listing_master_residential and listing_master_condo and listing_master_commercial there are three table and here is one primary key Ml_num in all table here i want to search data form one table these match mls number which table. thank you sir

Comment: have you have some suggestion

Comment: Please define "not working". I can't read minds. You didn't use good practices when ask the question (show table structure, show the expected result, etc..) Please update your question.